# How to inject ILogger<Startup> in .NET 6

Tags: .net-6.0, serilog, asp.net-core-6.0

Recently we moved from .NET 2 to .NET 6. I want to keep using **startup.cs** file. So I refactored **program.cs** and **startup.cs** files as below

**Program.cs**

```cs
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.File("logs/log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
        .CreateBootstrapLogger();
    Log.Information("Starting up!");
    
    try
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext());
            
        var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration, builder.Environment);
        startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);
        var app = builder.Build();
        startup.Configure(app);
        app.Run();    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "An unhandled exception occurred during bootstrapping");
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
    namespace Foo.Bar
    {
    
        public class Startup
        {
            private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
            private IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
    
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
                Environment = environment;
            }
          
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                
            }
            
            public void Configure(WebApplication app)
            {
                var logger = app.Logger;
                var appLifetime = app.Lifetime;            
    
                logger.LogInformation("Started Configure Method.");
    
                appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
                {
                    logger.LogInformation("Application started. {0}", DateTime.UtcNow);
                });
                
                appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() =>
                {
                    logger.LogInformation("Application stopped. {0}", DateTime.UtcNow);
                });      
    
    
            }
        }
    }
```

**appsettings.json**

```json
      "Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
          "Default": "Error",
          "Override": {
            "Foo.Bar.Startup": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning"
          }
        },
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "Console"
          }
        ]
      },
```

In appsettings I have configured override `"Foo.Bar.Startup": "Information"`. However It's not logging Information logs from `Configure()` method. I think this is because in configure method the logger in not `ILogger<Startup>`

But if I change override section to `"Foo.Bar": "Information"` then its logging Information from Startup.cs

I am trying to figure out what type of `ILogger<T>` is WebApplication.Logger (so I can just use that type in override section)
or How do I Inject `ILogger<Startup>` in startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

If you go and see class `WebApplication` is implemented you will see constructor

```cs
    internal WebApplication(IHost host)
    {
        _host = host;
        ApplicationBuilder = new ApplicationBuilder(host.Services, ServerFeatures);
        Logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger(Environment.ApplicationName ?? nameof(WebApplication));

        Properties[GlobalEndpointRouteBuilderKey] = this;
    }
```

And here we can see `Logger` is based on `host.Services`, so somewhere between `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` and `var app = builder.Build();` you need to call

```cs
        builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
        builder.Services.AddSerilog(logger, true);
```

I prefer to call this `ClearProviders` just in case to remove any possible logger existing by default, so `Serilog` is the only logger